# Create constructor method in controller in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have just started to learn `Yii`, where I have created one `PostController` Controller. In this controller I am having one requirement of using `Sessions`.

So I have created one constructor method and its code is as follows

```
public $session;
public function __construct() {
    $this->session = new CHttpSession;
    $this->session->open();
}
```

But after creating this constructor the controller was not working and gives error. And after deleting this code my controller was working perfectly. I have written this code inside constructor to not initialize the `Session` in each method for `actionCreate` and `actionUpdate`.

So my question is how can we create constructor in `Yii`?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, yii create CHttpSession automaticly, isn't it? See `CWebApplication::getSession()`, and when you try create new $_SESSION - you always will get error.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for comment but if I write the same code inside `actionCreate` it is working perfectly.

Comment: well, what error you got? Plz show it

Comment: @Sergey Actually I am in office right now and the code is present at my home so I don't remember what was the error.So I can't post it. Sorry..

Comment: if you use Yii , let it create everything for you. in Yii , you do Yii::app()->session['param'] , once you do that , yii will create the session for you .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply forgot to call parent constructor :

```
public function __construct()
{
  .....
  parent::__construct();
}
```

You could use [`beforeAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) instead of overriding `__construct`.

And *Sergey* is right, by default Yii will start session ([`autoStart`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#autoStart-detail)), you just have to use `Yii::app()->session`, e.g. :

```
Yii::app()->session['var'] = 'value';
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know..:)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct()
{
      parent::__construct($this->id, $this->module);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [init()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail) for that, but [found](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3884-init-or-contruct/) what people think **__construct** is better.