# Yii and PHP init vs construct issue

Tags: php, yii, constructor, init, magic-methods

I have a Register controller that inherits from Controller that inherits from CController.

When i use `__construct()` it fails to render the view.

I tried adding `parent::_construct($this->getUniqueID())` in the end of the function but no luck.

when i use `init()`, it's working.

Any idea how Yii is treating the construct vs init and why it can't find the rendered view?

### EDIT:

```
class Controller extends CController {
}


class RegisterController extends Controller{
    public function init() {
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

this case is working, when replacing init with __construct it fails to render the view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607722/create-constructor-method-in-controller-in-yii

Comment: @tinyByte, yes already saw that...and if you look at my question i added the parent::construct but it didnt help...this is where i took my idea to use init instead

Comment: did you see http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3884-init-or-contruct/, too?

Comment: @tinyByte I think this is my answer: "I agree with you that the method naming is very important. Here in Yii, init() method means that an object is already fully configured and some additional initialization work should be done in this method. "

though i would like to know why Yii is treating __construct in a different way.... thx anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would not recommend overwriting the contruct on any object in Yii.

I know its a bit counter intuitive, but Yii works around conventions, and a convention here is to just put you initialization code in the init() method.

If you want to take a look at the [Controller's source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CController.php#L778) code you'll see that I does a lot under the hood, it needs to check for [themes and controllers folders](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CController.php#L633) to resolve the view's path.

This mostly happens in the render method. but as rule of thumb, stick to the init() method.

Just stick to the convention and you will be fine, I can't think of a case that wouldn't fit well to just put aditional logic in the init method. its not like you are passing paramenters to the contructor, is it?